# How can I store Google's JWK in Azure securely?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, google-api, azure-keyvault

I am looking to connect to Google Cloud from Azure Cloud, but without having any credentials available in code. Ideally I want to store any credentials in KeyVault.

As far as I know it's not possible to store the Google JSON file directly in KeyVault.

I was thinking of breaking down the JSON and storing some parts such as the private_key_id, private_key, and private_key in KeyVault, then reconstructing the JWK when it's needed. However the maximum length allowed in KeyVault is 255.

So how can I store the JSON JWK securely in Azure KeyVault?

Comment: Did you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/multiline-secrets ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could download the JSON then store it to Azure Key Vault secret. And [there](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52480.azure-key-vault-overview.aspx) is a limitation of size. If your json is more than 25KB, please follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59766193/13308381).

> Secrets are octet sequences, with a maximum size of **25 KB** each.

**Steps using Poweshell:**

1.Install the `Az` powershell module

2.Login your account with `Connect-AzAccount`.

**Note**: Make sure your account has the correct secret permission in *Access policies* of your keyvault. If not, add it in the portal.

3.Follow the [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/multiline-secrets) that misha130 mentioned in the comment.

```
$string = '{
   "private_key":{
      "private_key_id": "xxx"
    }
}'
$Secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $string -AsPlainText -Force
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "keyvaultname" -Name "jwkjson" -SecretValue $Secret
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work